# code 404 message File nof found

Tags: python

I simply start a web server:
python -m http.server

and make a htm:
    
    
    
    Friends CGI Demo (static screen)

```
<BODY>
<H3>Friends list for:<I>NEW USER</I></H3>
<FORM ACTION = "/cgi-bin/test.py">
<B>Enter your Name:</B>
<INPUT TYPE = text NAME = person VALUE = "NEW USER" SIZE = 15>
<P><B>How many friends do you have?</B>
<INPUT TYPE = radio NAME = howmany VALUE = "0" CHECKED> 0
<INPUT TYPE = radio NAME = howmany VALUE = "10" > 10
<INPUT TYPE = radio NAME = howmany VALUE = "25" > 25
<INPUT TYPE = radio NAME = howmany VALUE = "50" > 50
<INPUT TYPE = radio NAME = howmany VALUE = "100" > 100
</P><INPUT TYPE = submit>
</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

then, write a test.py:
    #!c:\Python33\python.exe
    import cgi

```
print('Content-Type:text/html\n\n')
print('hello cgi')
```

it's a cgi example from CorePython, but it didnt work, i use python3.3, i google, and mend it, but it still not work, error is : code 404 message File nof found, look like test.py cannot be found, i have make a cgi-bin directory,and put test.py in it. i totally confused, look for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

python -m http.server --cgi 8000

The --cgi turns the python handler on.

Worked with your files above.

Comment: Not sure, but according to http://docs.python.org/2/library/cgihttpserver.html#module-CGIHTTPServer "Note The CGIHTTPServer module has been merged into http.server in Python 3. The 2to3 tool will automatically adapt imports when converting your sources to Python 3."

Comment: thank you very much, i have to learn more about the python3.3 documents

Answer (score 0):

Thinking and rambling out loud...

When I run "python -m http.server" on win7, the home directory is the c:\users[my id]\ directory.

```
I used http://localhost:8000
```

Is your cgi-bin in the correct directory?

I started the python web server via a command window. In the command window the 404 error showed.

Check you permissions to your cgi-bin and test.py. When I click on the \sendto\ link in my browser, I got:

```
    Error response
    Error code: 404
    Message: No permission to list directory.
    Error code explanation: 404 - Nothing matches the given URI.
```

Although http says 404, it really should be a 404.1. When I try to go to \sendto\ directory using windows explorer, I get access denied.

When I put a \cgi-bin\ in the directory I mentioned above, I was able to get a directory listing. When I create the files as you mentioned, it worked except the .py file contents was displayed.

What happens when you make \cgi-bin\test.py \cgi-bin\test.htm?

Comment: thanks for your answer, i run "python -m http.server" via cmd under my own directory 'tixiangshu', and cgi-bin is in 'tixiangshu' directory, but .py didnt work, it displayed like a text/plain, i dont know why, it's the access right?

Comment: Sounds like the permissions and paths are correct. I haven't run python as a web server. I configure IIS to run python scripts.  Maybe someone in the stockoverflow world can tell us how to get the python web server to launch/bind a python script. test.py showed as pain text for me.